# UPS Tracking On Google Sheet does not work

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, import, ups

I used following formula get UPS live tracking feed and it works fine until yesterday. I think UPS has updated their site and this formula does not work anymore. Any idea or suggestions for how to get the tracking update from UPS?

```
=Index(IMPORTXML("https://wwwapps.ups.com/WebTracking/track?track=yes&trackNums="&A1,"//*[@id='tt_spStatus']"),1)
```

Now I am getting an error:

> Imported content is empty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPS updated this webpage.  It no longer returns tracking information in the initial page response.  It now instead makes a separate AJAX request to retrieve the information after the page is loaded.

Use this formula instead with the URL updated to a different page on their site that returns tracking information in the initial page response:

```
=Index(IMPORTXML("https://wwwapps.ups.com/tracking/tracking.cgi?tracknum="&A1,"//*[@id='tt_spStatus']"),1)
```

Comment: This method doesn't seem to work anymore. Are there any modifications to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

With Delivery Time and status where A1 has tracking code.

> =index(IMPORTXML("https://wwwapps.ups.com/tracking/tracking.cgi?tracknum="&A1,"//*[contains(@class,'ups-group')]"),2)

Comment: this will only give me deliver date tho. How do I get the current status like in transit or Delivered. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Tracking with a few extra details (Where A1 is tracking no.):

```
=iferror(
  IMPORTXML(
    "https://wwwapps.ups.com/tracking/tracking.cgi?tracknum="&$A1,"//*[@id='tt_spStatus']")&iferror(": "&substitute(index(index(IMPORTHTML("https://wwwapps.ups.com/tracking/tracking.cgi?tracknum="&$A1,"table"),2),1),",  United States",""),""
  ),
  "--"
)
```

Result for package ready to ship: "Order Processed: Ready for UPS"

Result for in-transit parcel: "Picked Up: Atlanta, GA"

Answer (score 0):

None of these work for me in 2020 but here's what does:

Add this function in script editor:

```
function IMPORTJSON(url,xpath){

  try{
    // /rates/EUR
    var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
    var content = res.getContentText();
    var json = JSON.parse(content);

    var patharray = xpath.split("/");
    //Logger.log(patharray);

    for(var i=0;i<patharray.length;i++){
      json = json[patharray[i]];
    }

    //Logger.log(typeof(json));

    if(typeof(json) === "undefined"){
      return "Node Not Available";
    } else if(typeof(json) === "object"){
      var tempArr = [];

      for(var obj in json){
        tempArr.push([obj,json[obj]]);
      }
      return tempArr;
    } else if(typeof(json) !== "object") {
      return json;
    }
  }
  catch(err){
      return "Error getting data";  
  }

}
```

This formula will output transit status in your cell:

```
=IMPORTJSON(join("","http://shipit-api.herokuapp.com/api/carriers/ups/",A1),"activities/0/details")
```

I don't need the other details, so I made another cell that has a link to the ups tracking page if any other users need more information:

```
=HYPERLINK("https://www.ups.com/track?loc=en_US&tracknum="&A1&"&requester=WT/trackdetails)")
```